# Thumb Up and Down in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, sql

i was wondering how I could make a thumb up system in PHP and SQL. So like, you visit a page (for ex: content.php?id=5 and there would be 2 buttons. Thumb up and Thumb Down. Then it would show the Result. Something Like this http://funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/1755603/test+fail/ it would be good if it could go into negatives aswell. ex: http://funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/1757410/Me+Myself+And+I/

i would be using this for a gaming site.

Any ideas? I'm not sure how i would make the table structure.

Comment: You can design a table row called Vote that contains both up/down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

http://www.technabled.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

Simple: have a single int value default to zero.  A vote up increments it and a vote down decrements it.

More complex: Have a transactional table of votes up and down.  Use the aggregate to determine the rating.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little bit generic for a question. Still, if you don't care if a user votes twice in different sessions, you can simply do something along the lines of:

```
entry_id votes_up votes_down
```

Then save the entries already voted by an user in the session cookies (as an array). So when a user clicks to vote an entry, you can do

```
if (in_array( $this_entry_here, $_SESSION['entry_array']))
```

To check if he already voted.

Answer (score 0):

IF you looking for examples:

1. http://best-php-scripts.com/voting_scripts.htm
2. http://www.scripts.com/php-scripts/poll-and-voting-scripts/